# How to amend gnome extension

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Specifically this one - [Windows Blur Effects | GNOME Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/891/windows-blur-effects/) that blurs inactive windows.

Want to be able exclude some windows. And such feature must be already there (on github README it's marked as closed in version 3). But all i've found is:

```
const excludeList = []; // an array of wm-class to be excluded from filters
```

inside the extension.js. So 2 questions:

1. This array is what i looking for?
2. If yes, and i amend it with, let's say, ["Firefox"] - how to make changes active (do i need to "recompile" this extension.js)? Simple saving changes and switching extension off/on doesn't make any difference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to restart the GNOME shell in order to see the effect of the changes made.

If you're in an Xorg session, press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, then type `r` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

If you're in a Wayland session the above will not work, either reboot your system or log out and log in again.